# Como fazer a mensagem aparecer no corpo da janela e não no título?

Tags: python, tkinter, login

Estou tentando fazer uma tela de login, mas quando executo pra ver se a senha esta certa ou errada, a mensagem aparece no título, e não na janela.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
#cores ------------------------------
co0 = "#fof3f5" # preto
co1 = "#feffff" # branco
co2 = "#3fb5a3" # verde
co3 = "#38576b" # valor
co4 = "#403d3d" # letra

#criando janela ------------------------------

janela = Tk()
janela.title("")
janela.geometry("310x300")
janela.configure(background=co1)

#dividindo janela ------------------------------


frame_cima = Frame(janela,width=310,height=50,bg=co1,relief="flat")
frame_cima.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=1, sticky=NSEW)

frame_baixo = Frame(janela,width=310,height=250,bg=co1,relief="flat")
frame_baixo.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=1, sticky=NSEW)

#configurando o frame de cima ------------------------------
L1 = Label(frame_cima, text='LOGIN',anchor=NE,font=('ily 25'), bg =co1,fg = co4)
L1.place(x=5,y=5)

Linha1 = Label (frame_cima, text="",width=275,anchor=NW,font=('ily 1'), bg = co2)
Linha1.place(x=10,y=45)

credenciais = ['victor','1234']

def verificar_senha():
    nome = E_nome.get()
    senha = E_senha.get()

    if nome == "Lucas" and senha == "123456789":
     messagebox.showinfo('login,comfirmado seja bem vindo Lucas')
    elif credenciais [0] == nome and credenciais  [1]  == senha:
      messagebox.showinfo( 'seja bem vindo de volta' + credenciais [0])

    else:
        messagebox.showwarning('Erro verifiqu a senha e o nome') 

#configurando o freme de baixo ------------------------------
L_nome1 = Label(frame_baixo, text='Nome *',anchor=NW,font=('ily 10'), bg =co1,fg = co4)
L_nome1.place(x=14,y=20)

E_nome = Entry(frame_baixo,width=25,justify='left',font=("",13),highlightthickness=1,relief='solid',)
E_nome.place(x=14,y=50)

L_nome1 = Label(frame_baixo, text='Senha *',anchor=NW,font=('ily 10'), bg =co1,fg = co4)
L_nome1.place(x=14,y=100)

E_senha = Entry(frame_baixo,width=25,justify='left',font=("",13),highlightthickness=1,relief='solid',)
E_senha.place(x=14,y=130)

b_comfirmar = Button(frame_baixo,text='ENTRAR',command= verificar_senha,width=39,height=2,font="ily 8 bold",bg=co2,fg=co1,relief=RAISED)
b_comfirmar.place(x=14,y=180)


janela.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.messagebox.html), vemos que o primeiro parâmetro da função `showinfo` é `title` e o segundo é `message`. Como você não especificou nenhum parâmetro quando passou a mensagem como argumento, esse valor vai para o primeiro parâmetro.

Portanto, você deve usar `messagebox.showinfo(message="login,comfirmado seja bem vindo Lucas")` para que a mensagem vá corretamente para o corpo da janela.